# React JS Context API: Access Input Value From Another Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can I use context API to make a certain state global. For example, I have this input below in component `modalComponent.js`:

```
<Input type="select" name="assessInput" value={this.state.assessExam} onChange={this.handleAssessChange}>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="5">7</option>
  <option value="5">10</option>
</input>
```

In the same component I have initialized an empty state of `assessExam` as in:

```
state = {
    assessExam: ''
 };
```

And then I have a `handleAssessChange` function that changes the `assessExam` state based on what the user selects as in:

```
handleAssessChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ assessExam: e.target.value });
    };
```

Now the question is how can I get this state's value and log it out in a different component?

Comment: You want to store your state in the context and use the context in all the components that need access to the state. You should follow [these React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) as you seem to still be using class components instead of functional components.

Comment: I am actually already using react with redux to manage states, just not sure if I should use Redux to manage this state value as well since I am using redux  only to manage API states...

Comment: It's really up to you. Will it benefit you to use Redux rather than Context?

Comment: if you have redux already that seems like a good place to put all your global state

Answer (score 0):

Use Context API

Create a file called StateProvider.js

```javascript
import React,{createContext,useContext,useReducer} from 'react';

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider  = ({reducer,initialState,children})=>(
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer,initialState)}>
     {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

2nd step - create a file called reducer.js

```javascript
export const initialState = {
   user : "",
   image : "",
};

export const getBasketTotal = (basket)=>
    basket?.reduce((amount,item)=> item.price + amount,0);

const reducer = (state,action)=>{
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD__USER':
            return{
                ...state,
                user : action.name
                
            }
            case 'ADD__IMAGE':
                return{
                    ...state,
                    image : action.image
                    
                }
        default :
          return state
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

Change Index.js

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {initialState} from './reducer'
import reducer from './reducer'
import {StateProvider} from './Stateprovider'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Step 4 -  Add value to your context api

```javascript
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'

const [{ user },dispatch] = useStateValue();
setlink('/inbox');
dispatch({
   type : 'ADD__USER',
   name : username.trim()
})
```

step 5 - Access your context into other files

```javascript
import {useStateValue} from './Stateprovider'
const [{ user }] = useStateValue();
 
const onClick =(event)=>{
   console.log(user)
}
```